# Filtro de pesquisa com mais de um índice no array em javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

No momento, só consigo buscar os itens que estão na coluna `BAIRRO` no índice `[0]`, como faço para conseguir buscar por EMPREENDIMENTO no índice `[1]`, COMPLEMENTO no índice `2`, e VALOR no índice `5` ?

Abaixo, segue um print mostrando a tabela e o filtro de pesquisa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aqui, segue o código fonte de minha tabela

```
<table class="dataTable table table-bordered table-striped" id="myTable">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>BAIRRO</th>
            <th>EMPREENDIMENTO</th>
            <th>COMPLEMENTO</th>
            <th>PROPRIETÁRIO</th>
            <th>CONTATO</th>
            <th>VALOR</th>
            <th>CADASTRADO EM</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
           <?php
                 foreach ($propertyDetails as $agenciamento) {
                      echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>$agenciamento->bairro</td>";
                      echo "<td>$agenciamento->empreendimento</td>";
                      echo "<td>$agenciamento->apartamento</td>";
                      echo "<td>$agenciamento->proprietario</td>";
                      echo "<td>$agenciamento->contato</td>";
                      echo "<td>$agenciamento->valor</td>";
                      echo "<td>$agenciamento->cadastro</td>";
                      echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>

    </tbody>
```

E aqui, meu código em `JAVASCRIPT`

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0,1];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer um laço `for` dentro do laço `for` existente. O primeiro percorre as linhas e o segundo percorre as colunas dentro de cada linha.

Declare uma array com os índices das colunas que você quer percorrer:

```
var indices = [0,1,2,5];
```

E o `for` aninhado dentro do `for`:

```
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
 for(var x = 0; x < indices.length; x++){
     td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[indices[x]];
     if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          break;
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
     }
  }
}
```

O segundo `for` irá percorrer a array `indices`, cujos valores são os índices das colunas onde se quer filtrar.

Veja que coloquei um `break` ali no `if` porque se algo já foi encontrado naquela coluna, já não precisa continuar a verificar as outras colunas.